# Gather Cells and write it in Active Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

CollectTimesheetData.xlsm has the below headings in A1, B1 and C1 cells:

```
Employee Name  Project Name    Grand Billable Hours
```

I have created a Run button and it has the below macro in it. What I am trying to do is:

1. Ask the user to select a folder
2. Run though all the .xls files in that folder one by one
3. Read the cell values B7, B14 and R28 from all the xls files inside the selected folder
4. Write B7 in A2, B14 in B2 and R28 in C2 for 1st xls file,
5. Write B7 in A3, B14 in B3 and R28 in C3 for 2nd xls file,
6. Write B7 in A4, B14 in B4 and R28 in C4 for 3rd xls file, and so on.

What I have is the below macro:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim fd As Object, myfiles As String, result, tempfile As Workbook, j As Long, i As Long

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If fd.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

ChDir (fd.SelectedItems(1))

myfiles = Dir(fd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator & "*.xls")

ReDim result(1 To Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
j = 2

Do While myfiles <> ""

    Set tempfile = Workbooks.Open(myfiles)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = tempfile.Sheets(1).Range("B7")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = tempfile.Sheets(1).Range("B14")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = tempfile.Sheets(1).Range("R28")

    j = j + 1
    tempfile.Close 0
    myfiles = Dir

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

The problem is it runs, no error, no exception but nothing is written in the current active worksheet either.

What I am missing here, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realize that once

```
Set tempfile = Workbooks.Open(myfiles)
```

is executed, ActiveSheet becomes some sheet in the newly opened workbook?  The code is only transferring values from the first sheet in tempfile to some arbitrary sheet in the same file.

Comment: oh snap!! I feel dumb right now. I am gonna explicitly say the workbook and worksheet name and try it now. Thank you!

Comment: Used ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) and it worked! Thank you!