# Why ActiveSheet.Cells() don't work?

Tags: vba, excel

I'am working on a VBA Module that reads Cells from a column of the active Workbook - the Output of an other Tool -, nothing spectecular, but it seems that I missed something.
The Solutions of similar Questions I read and tested them, but without any luck.
[Get Value from a cell on a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404582/get-value-from-a-cell-on-a-worksheet?rq=1) or
[Gather Cells and write it in Active Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633721/gather-cells-and-write-it-in-active-worksheet#)
Here the Code until it throws "1004"

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileNameArray() As String
Dim VideoDataArray() As String
Dim TempString As String
Dim strPattern As String

Dim mot_H As Integer
Dim vok_H As Integer
Dim aufgest_H As Integer
Dim mot_S As Integer
Dim vok_S As Integer
Dim vis_Q As Integer
Dim aud_Q As Integer
Dim int_E As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'Nehme den Dateinamen
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Debug.Print FileName

'Zerlege den Dateinamen
FileNameArray() = Split(FileName, "_")

'Fülle ein Array mit den Daten
    For i = 0 To 50

    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    TempString = TempString & "_" & s & "_"

    Next i
```

I am sure it is only a trivial failure, but I can't find it at the Moment.
Thank you very much!

Comment: are you sure your `ActiveSheet` is the worksheet with the data you want `s` to refer to ? why not `s = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("wb_name").Cells(i, 1).Value` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rows start at 1, not 0 so you'll get an error when you're trying to access `.Cells(0,1)`. Start your `i` at 1 and it should be fine:

```
For i = 1 To 50
    '...
Next i
```